# add if condition in lambda python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, syntax-error

The following code, results in a syntax error.

```
def closest(lst, k, l):
    return lst[ min(range(len(lst)), key = lambda i: (abs(lst[i][0] - k)) if (lst [i][1] == l) else None)]

h = [ ([3,5],[63, 5]), ([3, 10],[65,10]) ]
lst =[ (3,5), (15,5), (60,5), (15,10), (40,10), (60,10) ]


for z in range(len(h)):
    print(closest(lst, h[z][1][0], h[z][1][1]))
```

For `[63, 5])` and `[65,10]` in `h`, I expect `(60,5)` and `(60,10)` in `lst` respectively, where `h[0][1][1] == lst[2][1]` and `h[1][1][1] == lst[5][[1]`, and `h[0][1][0]` closest to `lst[2][0]` and `h[1][1][0]` closest to `lst[5][[1]`

Comment: Indent the code properly and also include the error message you(with the line number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the error I get when I run your code:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File ".../test.py", line 9, in <module>
>     print(closest(lst, h[z][1][0], h[z][1][1]))
>   File ".../test.py", line 2, in closest
>     return lst[ min(range(len(lst)), key = lambda i: (abs(lst[i][0] - k)) if (lst [i][1] == l) else None)]
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
> ```

This error tells you that you are trying to compare integers with `None` during the execution of `min()`. This is because the lambda function you use for the key parameter sometimes returns an int and sometimes `None`. To prevent this error make sure that for all elements in the collection you are trying to minimize, the function you use for the key parameter returns values that can be compared with each other. So in this example, just return a really large integer when you want to reject an element as a possible minimum.